# Csv probleme in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, data-analysis

i'am working on a project and i have to deal with disgusting type of data into a csv file.

I know how to put the data into a variable but i can't delete [" "],["  "],from empty lines (not empty at all because there is space into it )
i have tried many things such as gsub with a regex, comparaison string etc etc but nothing works . It's maybe a question of data length because it has to go throught 38000 lines.

can you try it ?

```
ID ANN;Titre;[Vide];[Vide];ID PRO;ID CLI;Type ann;Prix;[0];[0.0];[0];ID Marque;Cat Véhicule;Cylindrée;Modèle;Année;Année 2;Date;Actif;[Vide];Etat;[0];[0];Achat;ABS;Garantie;Mois garantie;Frais port;Ref contructeur;Cat;sCat;ssCat;Image1;I1 ext;Image2;I2 ext;Image3;I3 ext;[0];[0];agpl_id;agpl_ref;agpl_nom;agpl_prix;agpl_qte;agpl_poids;agpl_desc;baseimageurl;Image 1;Image 1 text;Image 2;Image 2 text;Image 3;Image 3 text;Statut;Log;Log2;Statut Img;IDAP;StN
11;Électrique - Commodo -   Commodo gauche &amp; Commodo droit - Moto APRILIA 100 SCARABEO  2004;;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO
COMODO COMMODO DROIT
 
TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009
;55;0;1;10;0;0.40;0;8;1;100;SCARABEO ;2004;2009;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;7.91;;4;31;117;ann_11;jpg;ann_11_2;jpg;;;0;0;11;24173;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO COMODO COMMODO DROIT TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009;9.56;1;0.4;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;3/2/0/1/9/32019.jpg;;3/2/0/2/3/32023.jpg;;;;0;;;1;0;0
12;Moto APRILIA 100 SCARABEO  2004;;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO
DISQUE DE FREIN AVANT
 
TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009
4mm
;55;0;1;28;0;1.50;0;8;1;100;SCARABEO ;2004;2009;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;10.90;;2;13;74;ann_12;jpg;;;;;0;0;12;24145;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO DISQUE DE FREIN AVANT TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009;27.53;1;1.5;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;3/1/9/7/3/31973.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
15;Électrique - Allumage - Alternateur / Rotor - Stator - Moto APRILIA 100 SCARABEO  2004;;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO
ROTOR ALLUMAGE ALTERNATEUR
 
TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009
;55;0;1;30;0;1.00;0;8;1;100;SCARABEO ;2004;2009;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;9.49;;4;147;150;ann_15;jpg;;;;;0;0;15;24141;APRILIA 100 SCARABEO ROTOR ALLUMAGE ALTERNATEUR TYPE VAA 4TEMPS - 2004/2009;29.90;1;1;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;3/1/9/6/8/31968.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
69;Électrique - Relais et capteurs  - Relais divers - Moto APRILIA 125 RSV TUONO (R), (RACING) 2004;;APRILIA 1000 RSV R
5 RELAIS CENTRALES ELECTRIQUE
CAPTEUR CHUTE RENVERSEMENT
 
TYPE ZD4RRA - 2004/2005
;55;0;1;27;0;0.20;0;8;1;125;RSV TUONO (R), (RACING);2004;2005;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;6.79;;4;29;154;ann_69;jpg;ann_69_2;jpg;ann_69_3;jpg;0;0;69;170327;APRILIA 1000 RSV R 5 RELAIS CENTRALES ELECTRIQUE TYPE ZD4RRA - 2004/2005;26.90;1;0.2;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;2/7/0/2/4/1/270241.jpg;;2/7/0/2/4/2/270242.jpg;;2/7/0/2/4/3/270243.jpg;;0;;;1;0;0
103;Cycle - Frein arrière - Disque de frein - Moto APRILIA 1000 RS 1998;;APRILIA
125 RS-1998/09
125 TUONO-2004/05
250 RS-1995/05

1000 TUONO FIGHTER 02/05
1000 TUONO RACING 03/08
1000 TUONO RR 03/08
1000 RSV 1998/08
1000 RSV R 98/08
1000 RSV FACTORY 04/07
1000 RSV SP 99/03
1000 SL FALCO 00/04
DISQUE DE FREIN ARRIERE


4.8mm
Mini 4.5mm

;55;0;1;40;0;1.00;0;8;1;1000;RS;1998;2009;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;9.49;;2;14;75;ann_103;jpg;;;;;0;0;103;169793;APRILIA 1000 TUONO / RSV / FALCO-125 RS-250 RS-DISQUE DE FREIN ARRIERE;39.90;1;1;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;2/6/9/1/4/1/269141.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
112;Moto APRILIA 125 ATLANTIC 2002;;APRILIA 125 ATLANTIC
CABLE DE COMPTEUR
 
TYPE ZD4SP - 2002/2010
;55;0;1;9;0;0.15;0;8;1;125;ATLANTIC;2002;2010;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;6.79;;2;23;223;ann_112;jpg;;;;;0;0;112;112549;APRILIA 125 ATLANTIC CABLE DE COMPTEUR TYPE ZD4SP - 2002/2010;8.40;1;0.15;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/5/8/9/9/3/158993.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
128;Cycle - Jantes - Jante &amp; axe de roue - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
AXE DE ROUE ARRIERE
 
1995/2003
 
Nu sans vistendeur ni entretoises
;55;0;1;17;0;0.90;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;9.49;;2;15;194;ann_128;jpg;;;;;0;0;128;137394;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC AXE DE ROUE ARRIERE 1995/2003;16.90;1;0.9;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;2/0/0/7/7/3/200773.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
129;Cycle - Jantes - Jante &amp; axe de roue - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
AXE DE ROUE AVANT
&nbsp;
1995/2003
;55;0;1;17;0;0.40;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;7.91;;2;15;194;ann_129;jpg;;;;;0;0;129;42366;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC AXE DE ROUE AVANT 1995/2003;16.90;1;0.4;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/4/4/9/2/0/144920.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
130;Moteur - Echappement - Sonde lambda &amp; Valve échappement - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
BALANCIER BOITE 
 
- 1995/2003
ETAT OK
;55;0;1;12;0;0.30;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;7.91;;3;20;89;ann_130;jpg;ann_130_2;jpg;;;0;0;130;103916;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC BALANCIER BOITE  - 1995/2003;11.34;1;0.299;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/4/5/8/4/9/145849.jpg;;1/4/5/8/5/0/145850.jpg;;;;0;;;1;0;0
131;Cycle - Béquille - Béquille latérale / béquille centrale  - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
BEQUILLE LATERALE
 
1995/2003
;55;0;1;16;0;1.10;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;10.90;;2;9;53;ann_131;jpg;;;;;0;0;131;42367;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC BEQUILLE LATERALE 1995/2003;15.90;1;1.1;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/4/0/8/5/6/140856.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
132;Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
CACHE CARTER MOTEUR DROIT
 
1995/2003
 
Rapé léger
;55;0;1;6;0;2.00;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;10.90;;3;16;79;ann_132;jpg;;;;;0;0;132;56839;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC CACHE CARTER MOTEUR DROIT 1995/2003;5.90;1;2;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/4/5/0/7/0/145070.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
133;Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
CACHE CARTER MOTEUR GAUCHE
 
1995/2003
 
Rapé léger
;55;0;1;6;0;1.00;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;9.49;;3;16;79;ann_133;jpg;;;;;0;0;133;50829;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC CACHE CARTER MOTEUR GAUCHE 1995/2003;5.90;1;1;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;2/1/2/1/7/7/212177.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
135;Électrique - Eclairage - Clignotant - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
CLIGNOTANT ARRIERE GAUCHE
 
- 1995/2003
;55;0;1;9;0;0.10;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;6.79;;4;24;106;ann_135;jpg;;;;;0;0;135;170050;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC CLIGNOTANT ARRIERE GAUCHE - 1995/2003;8.90;1;0.1;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;2/6/9/6/3/0/269630.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
136;Moteur - Echappement - Collecteur &amp; Ligne d&#39;échappement  - Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
COLLECTEUR ECHAPPEMENT
 
1995/2003
;55;0;1;12;0;1.50;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;10.90;;3;20;87;ann_136;jpg;;;;;0;0;136;56829;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC COLLECTEUR ECHAPPEMENT 1995/2003;11.45;1;1.5;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;7/7/3/3/3/77333.jpg;;;;;;0;;;1;0;0
137;Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
FEU ARRIERE
&nbsp;
1995/2003
&nbsp;
Feu repeint
;55;0;1;10;0;0.50;0;8;1;125;CLASSIC;1995;2003;27/10/2020 14:34;1;;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;7.91;;4;24;104;ann_0;png;;;;;0;0;137;100693;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC FEU ARRIERE 1995/2003;9.71;1;0.5;desc;http://www.agpl.net/img/p/;1/4/0/8/7/0/140870.jpg;;;;;;0;[I137]:HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
;;5;0;0
139;Moto APRILIA 125 CLASSIC 1995;;APRILIA 125 CLASSIC
FLASQUE DE FREIN ARRIERE
```

here is my code

```rb
def analyze(document_csv)

        trash = []
        files = CSV.foreach((document_csv), headers: false, col_sep: "\n", skip_blanks: true) do |row|

           a = row.join.split(";")
           next if a == [" "] || a == ["  "]
           trash << a
        end

        trash.each do |str|
            print str
        end
    end
```

Please help me fixing this

bit of data  that i get from my code

````
["Embouts coupés"][" "][" "]["", "55", "0", "1", "37", "0", "5.00", "0", "234", "1", "650", "TL S", "1997", "2001", "27/10/2020 14:35", "1", "", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "15.90", "", "3", "20", "87", "ann_6778", "jpg", "ann_6778_2", "jpg", "ann_6778_3", "jpg", "0", "0", "6778", "67614", "SUZUKI 1000 TLS COLLECTEUR D'ECHAPPEMENT N°1 TYPE JS1AG31/21 1997/2001", "36.65", "1", "5", "desc", "http://www.agpl.net/img/p/", "1/4/4/4/9/1/144491.jpg", "", "1/4/4/4/9/2/144492.jpg", "", "1/4/5/2/9/3/145293.jpg", "", "0", "", "", "1", "0", "0"]["6824", "Moto SUZUKI 1100 GSX F 1988", "", "SUZUKI 1100 GSXF"]["POIGNEE DE MAINTIEN PASSAGER ARRIERE DROITE"][" "]```
````

Comment: Calling that mess "CSV" is being very generous. Do you have any documentation on how the thing is *supposed* to be formatted, or is this a task of reverse engineering? Either way, I don't envy you.

Comment: I don't have nothing my boss is just horrible

Comment: `col_sep: "\n"` - col_sep seems to be `;`

Comment: It seems to be ; but its not because the work after this part is to recompose the data to a normal line every ; are for rows in the futur

Comment: Readers might better understand your problem if you were to make your example much shorter and--*importantly*--show the desired result. Also, I don't understand, '...can't delete [" "],[" "],from empty lines...'. The brackets and comma are unclear. Are you simply referring to lines that contain only spaces?

Comment: You edited to add, "bit of data from my code". Presumably you don't want that (in part because it is not valid Ruby object). What do you want in place of that? Just because that may be obvious to you does not mean that it's obvious to readers. The number 1 rule when giving an example is to show the desired result, here as a Ruby object (an array of strings perhaps).

Comment: If it were me, I'd read the whole file in as text, process the text, then look at converting to CSV afterwards ... I've had to do similar before. If I get time later I'll add a code answer

Comment: Bad news, you probably cannot fix this file automatically.  you have html code embedded in there, which includes `&amp;` and others.  you could try to replace all the `&[^;]+;` codes you find with something else before parsing, but you'd be much better off getting this file in _any_ other format